# Spring cloud dataflow local mode limitations and LDAP security

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to setup Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) to run in Local mode and how few questions which may help me decide if its a suitable platform for my requirements.

1. Even though the recommendation is to use Cloud Foundry, Kubernetes etc as task execution environment my preference to run things on production is local mode mainly because I don't have a lot of workload and cant deal with all the additional complexity. Now in local mode will I be able to run all types of SCDF apps, namely Streams, Jobs and tasks with no limitations? Some parts of the document mentions that only Jobs can be run in local mode.
2. Security - I am looking to put controls in place around deployment of apps and operational access to the tool (dashboard) and do see the support for LDAP with roles as an option but the whole concept of using Cloudfoundry UAA, another product to drive the user managements seems like an overkill. Is there no way to configure the tool with an existing LDAP server? Found the following in one of the LDAP issues in Github but its not clear whether it uses UAA in its docker image. Worst case I wont mind if the dashboard can be run in a view/read only mode.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from v2.0, we delegate to [UAA](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa) for authentication and authorization. There are a variety of write-ups on this matter; a more comprehensive one to look at is the end-to-end sample on how all this could be put together locally. You do not need CF or K8s, all this can run locally also. We rely on UAA as the gateway to standardize on end-to-end SSO across all the client tools, including shell, dashboard, RESTful APIs, CTR, etc.,

Sample: [SCDF Security with UAA + LDAP](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/security-ldap-uaa-example). For further reading, please refer to the [security section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-local-security) in the ref. guide.

Lastly, we do not recommend Local for a production install, but I understand that resiliency and/or restartability of apps under failure condition is not a requirement for some workloads.

Answer (score 3):

If Spring Cloud Data Flow were a purely monolithic application, integrating all aspects of security directly into the app is definitely easier to to wrap one's mind around. This is how Spring Cloud Data Flow originally started out from a security perspective and thus, versions of Spring Cloud Dataflow `<2.0.0` supported what we labelled *traditional security*.

However, even before `2.0.x` Spring Cloud Data Flow:

- Had to integrate with external platforms such as [Cloud Foundry](https://www.cloudfoundry.org/)
- Became more and more microservices oriented (e.g. by using [Skipper](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-skipper/))

As a result 2 parallel security architectures had emerged, one using *traditional security* and the other one driven by [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/)/[OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/).

This started to become increasingly harder to maintain and for `2.0.x` we decided to exclusively focus on OAuth2/OpenID Connect. However, we still had to support a rich set of enterprise features such as Roles, LDAP integration etc. As such, we find that the open-source, production-ready [CloudFoundry User Account and Authentication (UAA) Server](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa) is an excelling choice. Its LDAP support and features actually exceeds the features offered by Spring Cloud Dataflow `<2.0.0`.

So yes, in order to setup security for Spring Cloud Data Flow locally, you need to run the UAA. And the UAA would also provide the LDAP support. Technically, Spring Cloud Data Flow has no awareness of the LDAP setup at all.

I hope this provides some background regarding how the Spring Cloud Data Flow security architecture emerged. Please have a look at the reference documentation and the aforementioned [SCDF Security with UAA + LDAP example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/security-ldap-uaa-example). Don't hesitate to reach out in case of further questions!

Disclaimer: I am a committer on the project.

Comment: Thanks @gunnar-hillert for the clarification. I went through the UAA/LDAP configuration but see that it needs it own LDAP server. Our firm already has an enterprise LDAP user so managing another one just for SCDF is going to be bit of a trouble. Native LDAP support would have been a great option but may be its asking for too much. I may have to look at OAuth2 as an alternative.

Comment: I hope I understood you correctly: You can configure UAA to use an existing LDAP server. It does **not** require a separate LDAP server instance.

Comment: I misunderstood this for some reason. This makes sense now and should work for me. Will go through the UAA LDAP setup configurations. Thanks for your help.